# Arquillan EJB3 unit test - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: unit-testing, ejb, jboss-arquillian

I'm running an EJB unit test with Arquillian but I receive

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder
```

my test class is this

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class) 
public class EjbTest {
  @Inject
  private RepAlertManagerImpl ejb;


  @Deployment
  public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
     return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "foo.jar")
    .addClasses(RepAlertManagerImpl.class)
    .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
  }

  @Test
  public void testEjb() throws IOException, SQLException {

    try 
    {                       
        List<Long> result = ejb.doSomething("ENTRATE");

        for(Long temp:result){
            System.out.println(temp);
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

the jar I use for this client are

arquillian-container-test-api-1.1.7.Final; 
arquillian-junit-core-1.1.7.Final; 
junit-4.12

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved with gradle.

My build.gradle contains:

```
compile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
compile 'org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:1.1.7.Final'
```

just type **gradle eclipse** from build.gradle file dir (project directory)